# "Satisfying" or "satisfactory" or another word?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

1. In the following sentence, it is better to use "satisfying" or is there another good word?
2. After "boiler room" should I use "and" or a comma?

> On one of my main projects, I was attempted to design a steam boiler room, the results were very satisfying.

Comment: As far as the comma, is the room for the purposes of housing a steam boiler, or is the room full of steam and also has a boiler?

Comment: the steam boiler room is a room and contains steam boilers :)

Comment: That's a relief!  :-)

Comment: Did you attempt to design the boiler room, or did you actually design the boiler room?  The word "attempt" would suggest that you may have failed in completing this task.

Comment: I actually designed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I'd use 'satisfactory':

> fulfilling expectations or needs; acceptable, though not outstanding or perfect
>
> ([Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/satisfactory))

Over satisfying:

> giving fulfillment or the pleasure associated with this
>
> ([Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/satisfying))

Since it is a more technical context and in my experience satisfying is more often used to describe intangibles/feelings. ("My client was satisfied with the results" would be appropriate, however).

In your sentence the 'was' in "I was attempted to" is inappropriate. Since you have two verbs ('attempted' and 'were') you need a conjunction ('and', 'but', 'or', ';'):

"On one of my main projects, I attempted to design a steam boiler room and the results were very satisfactory."

My personal preference would be to eliminate the "I attempted to design" for "I designed" and change the "and the results were very satisfactory" to a second sentence "My client was very satisfied with the results" which allows you to explain the metric or person that found the design satisfactory:

"On one of my main projects, I designed a steam boiler room. My client was very satisfied with the results."

Comment: You need to cite the sources for your definitions.

Comment: @Laurel is that sufficient?

Comment: Well, the actual source for these definitions is [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/). Can you cite that instead (with a link to the entry preferably). Thanks!

Comment: @Laurel Thanks--didn't know where google was pulling from and liked theirs better than Dictionary.com or Merriam Webster

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the room houses a steam boiler, the noun phrase "steam boiler room" should not have a comma.
Also, you really have two sentences and need a conjunction (like "and") to join them (as you suspected) where the comma is.

Satisfying would imply that you are the customer received some pleasure in your boiler room's design (e.g. you really enjoyed designing the room).  If the design of the room met the room's specifications, you could say that it was satisfactory.

As an engineer, I would just call it a boiler room.  Unless the working fluid is not water (e.g. an ORC facility utilizing, say, R11) everyone expects steam to be the vapor coming from the boiler.

Comment: thank you dear m_a_s. how about question number 1?

Comment: Oops, I missed that.  Are you trying to say that you enjoyed designing the room, or are you saying that the people evaluating the work were pleased with the results?

Comment: I want to say everybody who uses this facility and also the Employer are pleased with the results.

Comment: "Satisfactory" implies that the work was done, but nothing outstanding or perfect was achieved.  If you want to say it was better than that, consider what you said (e.g.  "... and people using this facility are pleased with the results").

Comment: then satisfying is better

Comment: No, they are different.  Satisfaction is in the heart.  Satisfactory designs meet customer specifications.